# How to install Node.js with PHP Curl?

Tags: php, apache, node.js, curl

I'm trying to find how to install Node.js on my apache server, but I don't have access to the console (SSH) on my server. Is it possible to install Node with PHP Curl ?

I've already downloaded [the source code](https://github.com/joyent/node) and I put it on my server, but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: If you don't have shell access to your server, how do you expect to run a node instance?

Comment: Try: http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/ - but it might not work. Your question in the current form is not clearly answerable anyway. Also upgrade your hosting plan to include SSH (or get a new hoster) instead of trying to do other things.

Comment: @Twisted1919 I don't know Node yet, for the moment I'm trying to install it. And it seems to be a complicated task :o

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r I'll have a look at your link

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible with PHP and some filthy `system()` calls, but if you can execute those Commands in a PHP context, why don't you have any access to the server otherwise?

<s>I would ask someone to give you access to the server directly or let the admins install node.js for you.</s>

Due to the fact that you're the admin of that server and you don't know how to enbale SSH and even not how to install node.js (which is pretty straightforward) I recommend you to read something about administering servers: [this](https://speakerdeck.com/futureshocked/a-linux-server-administration-tutorial-for-beginners) as well as [this link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/index.html) might help you.

Furthermore, [here's](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-openssh-server-installation-and-configuration/) a tutorial on how to enable `sshd` on your server and [here's](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) a link on how to build and install node.js.

But I still ask myself *how* do you even work with the server if you have no access to it in a way...

Comment: It's a personal server so I'm the admin !

Comment: So why do you have _no_ other access to your server? Consider enable `sshd` or - if it's a Windows machine - RDP.

Comment: I can't enabled it on my server :s

Comment: Thanks :). I've only a FTP access and I'm on a windows computer